# Dynamic UICollectionView -> errors and visual layout problems

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

This is the view I want to replicate:

[image]

I assume it is a `UICollectionView`. The width and height should be dynamically calculated based on the content, that is the point I am struggling with.

I created a project where the `UICollectionView` does not behave like I want: https://github.com/Jasperav/CollectionViewDynamic/blob/master/UIKitTest/ViewController.swift. You can just run the project and see the problem for yourself.

Every time a new `Emoji` is added, the `reloadData` method can be called and the `UICollectionView` size should be equal to the content size **but with a maximum width**.
This is how it looks like when 1 emoji is added (horrible):

[image]

It is really weird, the cell is not centered and I get layout errors in the console. When 2 emoji's are added, I would expect the line up next to each other, but they end up beneath each other...

[image]

There is enough space for the cells to be next to each other.
What am I doing wrong? I calculate the cell's size correctly when I inspect the values in the visual debugger. I think I am doing a lot of manual work to make sure the `UICollectionView` size is correct, but I don't get it right.

Am I overcomplicating stuff? What I want looks pretty basic to me. This is my first time doing something with the `UICollectionView` though.

This is how the `addEmoji` method looks like, the whole code can be seen in the link I mentioned above:

```
func addEmoji(emoji: Emoji) {
    emojis.append(emoji)

    var width: CGFloat = 0

    for emoji in emojis {
        width += emoji.size().width
    }

    let finalWidth = min(width, 280)

    // Add some breath
    widthAnchor_.constant = finalWidth + 5

    reloadData()

    heightAnchor_.constant = collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
}
```

Comment: you may looking for somting like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539979/left-align-cells-in-uicollectionview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added small changes to your code and now all works fine (changes is marked with a comment `// NEW`):
https://gist.github.com/sa1dai/b50bec10438b439a8c74cc6e8071bcf4?ts=4

The key idea is not to update `heightAnchor_.constant` in `addEmoji` function, but using `contentSizeObservation` (I took the idea of `contentSizeObservation` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68242293/19039804)).